# Using "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" in Java

Tags: java, mysql, load

I have a cvs file which schema is, every field is surrounded with ", and seperated by , and every tuple is a newline with \n

So in my Java file, I wrote

```
                String path = "o.csv";
                String esquel = " LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE " + path +
                            " INTO TABLE recommendations " +
                            " FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' ENCLOSED BY \'\"'" +
                            " LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'";
```

And I execute the statement with the following statement

```
statement.executeUpdate(esquel);
```

But it throws an SQLException which says:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'o.csv INTO
>   TABLE recommendations  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES'
>   at line 1

What is my error ?

I would be appreciate if you can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I got it ! I didn't surround my path file with '.

New sql statement should be:

```
String esquel = " LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + path +
                            "' INTO TABLE recommendations " +
                            " FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' ENCLOSED BY \'\"'" +
                            " LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\'";
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is working code which I tested:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class LoadTRPLog2MySql {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Class driver_class = null;
        try {
            driver_class = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("found driver" + driver_class);


        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysqlserver.com:3306/dbname", "myid","pwd");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Established connection to " + connection.getMetaData().getURL());
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            Statement statement1 = connection.createStatement();
            //windows
            //statement1.executeUpdate( "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\senthil_sivasamy\\Documents\\Projects\\messageprocessing\\log.txt' INTO TABLE  trpwatchlog_tb FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'");
            //linux  ( " LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/username/logname.log' INTO TABLE  logname.log FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'");
            statement.executeUpdate( "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/username/avail30trplog' INTO TABLE  logname.log FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'");

            statement1.execute("select * from dbname.tablelog_tb");
            ResultSet rs = statement1.getResultSet();
            System.out.println("Row hostname and timestamp");
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Row hostname and timestamp");
                System.out.println(rs.getRow());
                System.out.println(""+rs.getString("hostname"));
                System.out.println(""+rs.getString("timestamp"));
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
        } finally {
            if (statement != null) {
                try {
                    statement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```