# Can we read and insert .CSV file directly into MySQL database using JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

I want to know can I directly read and insert .csv file into my database or I need to read records one by one and insert them into my database.

Comment: Directly or using java? and how it's related to oracle?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html or http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/

Comment: Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) maybe this helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649160/using-load-data-local-infile-in-java)

Comment: Using Java i need to read and insert .csv file into database

Answer (score 1):

you can try this query in your java program

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/filename.csv'
INTO TABLE tablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: thanks Kishore, So could u plz guide me how to use this statement with JDBC

Comment: st = con.prepareStatement("LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/filename.csv'
INTO TABLE tablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';");
rs = st.executeQuery();

Comment: Thanks Kishore , will it  load the whole csv file into my database, or it fetches row by row n then insert into my database.

Comment: One more thing , will it parse the data types implicitly while loading into database or it is programmer's responsibility to parse it into desired type.

Comment: with respect to programmer there is no need to parse all those are done implicitly in API and the whole csv file will be loaded

Comment: Kishore, if we try to do same thing in JAVA with oracle.What changes do we need to make. I mean LOAD DATA INFILE will work over there or we need to achieve this by different way ??

Comment: it is the same way but you just need to change the jdbc drive class and user credentials rest all are same

Comment: Kishore ,can you provide me sample code for the same ..It will help me to understand it more

Comment: the following link will give you all the basic example wrt oracle JDBC,    http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file location'  -- File Name e.g /tmp/test.sql
INTO TABLE tablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS; -- If want to ignore header
```