# load data query is not working with INSERT/REPLACE option

Tags: java, mysql, load-data-infile

I am trying to upload data from CSV file into a mysql database table but i am getting error "java.sql.SQLException: Invalid utf8 character string: '' " when using INSERT/REPLACE option in load data query. but the same query works fine without INSERT/REPLACE option.

**Query:**

```
Statement  stmt = conn.createStatement(
ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

String  query = "LOAD DATA  INFILE 'D:\\"+flnm+"'  REPLACE INTO TABLE prfl_hntr " 
+ "FIELDS TERMINATED by ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES"
+ " (candidate, phone, mailid, skill, texp, rexp, pctc,np);";
stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

I have verified the syntax in mysql documentation- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html.

Please note that i need to use REPLACE/IGNORE option in the query to eliminate duplicate entries.

Comment: LOAD DATA **LOCAL** INFILE '/home/xxxxx/conf.csv'
INTO TABLE configuration 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;

Comment: and also check csv file permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649160/using-load-data-local-infile-in-java)

Comment: Hi hussain there was a typo in question. The problem is occuring when i am issuing command with REPLACE option. The query works fine without REPLACE option as suggested in the post in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right the issue is not with the syntax. The issue might be with difference in the characterset between Mysql table and your CSV file. I had a similar problem and resolved it by mentioning the characterset in the query. Try the query given below it should work and make sure your CSV file has data supported by Mysql table.

**Query:**

```
String  query = "LOAD DATA  INFILE 'D:\\"+flnm+"'  REPLACE INTO TABLE prfl_hntr " 
+"character set latin1 "
+ "FIELDS TERMINATED by ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES"
+ " (candidate, phone, mailid, skill, texp, rexp, pctc,np);";
stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

Further you can follow the answer by @RolandoMySQLDBA for this question-: [Trying to do LOAD DATA INFILE with REPLACE and AUTO_INCREMENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801302/trying-to-do-load-data-infile-with-replace-and-auto-increment?rq=1)
It worked wonders for me.

Answer (score 0):

LOAD DATA **LOCAL** INFILE '/home/xxxxx/conf.csv' INTO TABLE configuration FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;

try this once.

Comment: Hi hussain, Please take into account that i need to use either IGNORE or REPLACE option because am trying to avoid duplicates when loading data. Also please note that this question is not a duplicate because this issue is not addressed in other post.